# Can I customize the label of OK and Cancel buttons of ckeditor plugin dialog

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, customization

I have plugin created into the CK editor JS framework. I was able to show a dialog for my plugin with few fields. But I need to control the OK and Cancel buttons css properties like the label, color etc. It this customization possible ?

Answer (score 1):

There is **override** method which overrides passed in parameters.  It works for me on Ckeditor 4. Try it:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'getlinkDialog', function ( editor ) {
    return {
        title: 'Dialog title',
        minWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 70,
        contents: [
            {
                id: 'getlink-basic',
                label: 'Basic Settings',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'link',
                        label: 'Enter your name'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        buttons: [
        CKEDITOR.dialog.okButton.override( { label : 'My Label'} ),
        CKEDITOR.dialog.cancelButton.override( {} )
        ],
        onOk: function() {
           //Your code
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two approaches here:

- You can customize buttons uing [`CKEDITOR.dialog.definition#buttons`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition-property-buttons) property.
- You could override [`CKEDITOR.dialog.okButton`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog-static-method-okButton) method - more hacky, thus I'd recommend you trying with the first one.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried both the ways before posting int the forum and none seems to work.
The OK and Cancel seems to static buttons in the dialogue definitions and this is their implementation, which looks like we cant override them easily.

Comment: okButton: function () {var a = function (a, b) {
     b = b || {};
     return CKEDITOR.tools.extend({
      id: "ok",
      type: "button",
      label: a.lang.common.ok,
      "class": "cke_dialog_ui_button_ok",
      onClick: function (a) {
       a = a.data.dialog;
       !1 !== a.fire("ok", {
        hide: !0
       }).hide && a.hide()
      }
     }, b, !0)
    };
    a.type = "button";
    a.override = function (b) {
     return CKEDITOR.tools.extend(function (c) {
      return a(c, b)
     }, {
      type: "button"
     }, !0)
    };
    return a
   }

Comment: To be precise, the tried customizing the  CKEDITOR.dialog.definition#buttons in the onLoad handler of the dialogue. It seems to change it in the object (evaluated in the console) but not in the UI.

Comment: "It seems to change it in the object (evaluated in the console) but not in the UI." - I assume it's due to the  fact that you might be overriding it *after* the dialog has been created, is that the case?

Comment: Yes that is right. Like I told I was using the onLoad handler for the dialog. Is it something like after the dialog is loaded and if I make change in the object I have to do something extra to reflect it in the UI ?

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and none of the pretty solutions worked for me. That's why i used the uglier but working solution.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
                        // Take the dialog window name and its definition from the event data.
                        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
                        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
                        console.log("dialogDefinition", dialogDefinition);
                        console.log("dialogName", dialogName);
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            console.log("$('.cke_dialog_ui_button_ok').length", $('.cke_dialog_ui_button_ok').length);
                            $('span', '.cke_dialog_ui_button_ok').html("Save");
                        }, 100);

                    });
```

You will not even notice when was the text changed. If there is any better alternatives, please share.

Comment: Yup ugly. Might not be a option for production code :) anyways thank you.

Comment: @Oceanvijai agreed. But i did not find anything which worked for me in the image2 plugin. And i can't override image2 files directly. I hope someone can provide better solution so that i can avoid this scrappy one.